# calling boolean method, heads or tails

Tags: java, boolean

I'm wrote a method to simulate a coin toss, however, I do not know how to call this method in the main. Tips would really be appreciated! 
(Here is the method, I didn't post the entire code because there are 8 other methods in this code).

```
 public static boolean headsOrTails()
 {
   boolean coinState;
   if (Math.random() < 0.5) {//heads 50% of the time 
     coinState = true; //heads
   }
   else {    
     coinState = false; //tails
   }
   return coinState;
 }
```

Comment: Just call the method in your main method like headsOrTails();

Comment: Your method could be simplified to `public static boolean headsOrTails() { return Math.random() < 0.5; }`. The result of comparison operators like `<` already *is* a boolean, so you can just return that result directly without the if/else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call like :

```
public class Abc {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(headsOrTails());
   }

   public static boolean headsOrTails() {

       boolean coinState;
       if (Math.random() < 0.5) {//heads 50% of the time 
          coinState = true; //heads
       } else {    
          coinState = false; //tails
       }
       return coinState;
   }

}
```

and it will print the output of the function as **true** or **false**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean isHead = headsOrTails();
if(isHead){
     System.out.println("Heads");
}else{
     System.out.println("Tails");
}
```

if value of isHead is `true` you have a Head :)

Comment: I tried this, now how can I get the program to print something out indicating the coinState?

Answer (score 0):

You can also improve readability of your code by shortening the boolean evaluation (like Boann mentioned):

```
public class CoinToss {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        headsOrTails();
    }

    public static boolean headsOrTails() {
        return Math.random() < 0.5;
    }
}
```